# Help displaying an image in a java applet

Tags: java, image, applet, graphics2d

Below is a simple applet im writing to display a single picture. The code compiles fine, and the applet loads but the image file is never drawn to the applet. Im thinking that it cant find the image using the this.getImage(appletBaseURL, filename); I have the image file stored in all the folders associated with this package but its still not drawing it.

```
    import java.applet.Applet;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


   public class imageTest extends Applet {

    private Image spaceShip;    
    private final String filename = "spaceshipcropped.jpg";        
    public void init() {

        java.net.URL appletBaseURL = getCodeBase();
        File file = new File("spaceshipcropped.jpg");
        try {
            spaceShip = ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(imageTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;    
        g2d.drawImage(spaceShip, 0,0, null);
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
       repaint();
    }
}
```

After i made theses changes it worked. thank you all very much for your help!

Comment: Applets are not simple to develop or deploy.  At your stage of understanding, I would advise steering clear of them.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't call `setSize()` in an applet.  The size is set by HTML.
2. Don't code in AWT in this millennium.
3. The object passed to a  Swing component should be a `Graphics2D` object, but I've never heard the same said of an `Applet`.  Are you checking the Java Console?
4. That code has some redundant imports.
5. In the `paint` method, check to see if the image is `null`.
6. The JavaDocs for the `getImage(URL,String)` method state *"This method always returns immediately, whether or not the image exists."*  Either add a `MediaTracker` or join us in the 3rd millennium and use `ImageIO.read(URL)` - which blocks until the image is loaded.

I expect that fixing point 6 will solve the problem, but attend to the other 5 points as well.

Comment: ok so i added 

try {
            spaceShip = ImageIO.read(appletBaseURL);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(imageTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

in the init method. and removed the previous getImage(url, string) call. still not displaying the image. Working on correcting the other things you mentioned here as well. Any other suggestions?

Comment: *"Any other suggestions?"*  1) Finish attending to the other 5 points.  2) Add changed code into your question as an edit, rather than including it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
public void update(Graphcs g) {
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: ok, i added that as a method right after the paint method, but it didn't change it. The applet still pops up a blank grey screen.